# gomobile bind hello error

Tags: go, gomobile

Go 1.5 and 1.6 both new installs with gvm, I'm trying to create a android binding of the basic hello world example.

Ubuntu 14.4 long support on a old 32bit laptop i use for trying new things. After getting gomobile and gomobile init everything works. can build and install.  The android sdk is new and properly set.  I just can't find anything about the error.

gomobile bind hello

> gomobile: loadExportData failed go install -p=2
>   -pkgdir=/home/mrlarge/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.6/global/pkg/gomobile/pkg_android_amd64
>   -tags="" -gcflags=-shared -ldflags=-shared hello failed: exit status 2

## hello

```
/home/mrlarge/.gvm/gos/go1.6/pkg/tool/linux_386/link: -shared and -buildmode=pie are incompatible
```

P.s. Sorry the top part must of got deleted, Sleepy touchpad error i suppose..

Comment: We need a little bit more details to go on, also update gomobile and maybe try go tip.

Comment: tried updating everything, didn't help.... new to go, whats go tip.  Just Googled it all i get are tips for go lol

Comment: Go tip as in go from git, sorry I should have cleared that out.

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/install/source

Comment: It was an error in go1.6.2 that caused it i downgraded to 1.6 and everything was fixed.  Its reported.

Answer (score 1):

It was an error in go1.6.2 that caused it i downgraded to 1.6 and everything was fixed. Its reported